# Why are underlying TCP connections are released so late?

Tags: http, tcp, tcpdump, persistent-connection

[image: the tcp stream of the webservice call]

---

As you see above, the tcp connection release so slow.
I'm wondering how it happened and if it affect my program (http layer)?

Comment: Connection doesn't look slow, it just looks like data was sent then after a while it closed. Please put in more details, research what's using that port and show your data that indicates that you're connection is slow and what you mean by slow.

Answer (score 2):

This is [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) that defined by HTTP/1.1. When client makes requests to the server several requests can share one underlying TCP connection.

In your case request was performed and system waits for a while expecting other request. After 30 seconds inactivity it considers connection as idle and close it (sends TCP FIN).

About impact to the system: some resources are consumed for TCP connection handling. This may be an issue on huge servers handling millions requests but I don't think that this is your case.